# Is there a way to mount two folders into one mounting point, so that folders are mirrored?

Tags: filesystems, mount, raid, mirror, cloud

I want some tool like

```
$ mirroring_mount  ~/first_location ~/second_location ~/mount_point
```

So, when I edit file in `~/mount_point`, it is edited in both locations, and if `~/first_location` and `~/second_location` are not identical, I get an error. Is there such a tool?

Why I want it: `first_location` and `second_location` are folders in clouds, that are mounted to fs. I do not trust clouds, as I think that they can fail some day, or erase some of my files, that's why I want to mirror them. Even better would be if I could not only mirror clouds, but do something like RAID 5 on 3 clouds.

update. 
My access to clouds is limited to file operations. All I have is just a folder in google.drive, which is mounted using davfs.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify what you mean by your last sentence. _What specifically_ would be better than RAID1 across two cloud storage providers?

Comment: Have you considered [DRBD](https://www.drbd.org/en/) or possibly [OCFS2](https://oss.oracle.com/projects/ocfs2/)?

Comment: Related: http://serverfault.com/questions/411338/is-there-an-async-fuse-filesystem-for-replication